# Why won't less-than operator work between these two strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here's my code, super new to python. Struggling to understand why if I use < it always thinks is less than even though it will print a higher number. If I use greater than it works just fine. What am I missing? Here's my code, super new to python. Struggling to understand why if I use `<` it always thinks is less than even though it will print a higher number. If I use greater than it works just fine. What am I missing?

```
import time
t=time.localtime()
msttime=time.strftime("%H",t)
if(msttime < '2'):
    print(msttime)
else:
    print("This calculation believes msttime is greater than 2")
```

Comment: With strings, lt and gt are calculated in alphabetical order not numeric. `'2' > '1000'` because `2` comes after `1000` in the dictionary.

Comment: See Wikipedia article [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) which is how Python compares strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will give you the expected result:

```
import time

t = time.localtime()
msttime = time.strftime("%H", t)

if (int(msttime) < 2):
    print(msttime)
else:
    print("This calculation believes msttime is greater than 2")
```

The reason is that `"18"` < `"2"` lexographically, but `18` > `2` numerically. This is because the lexographical comparison has no regard for the second digit. Since `1` is before `2`, the comparison ends there. In the numerical comparison, all digits are accounted for.

Comment: very cool. thank you so much. makes perfect sense.

Comment: @will.ditch No problem, consider accepting the answer by pressing the checkmark. Gives both you and I reputation.